# How to execute method in child controller for bootstrap modal instance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal instance that i have opened from parent controller , now i have added method on checkbox `checkedValue` that i am trying to invoke from child controller but i am getting error `Cannot read property 'attuid' of undefined at ChildScope.$scope.checkedValue (newUserModal.controller.js:22)` Any idea  how can i invoke method in child controller ?

newUserModal.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in userList track by $index">
          <td st-ratio="20">{{user.attuid}}</td>
          <td st-ratio="30">{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
          <td st-ratio="15" ng-bind-html="user.type"></td>
          <td st-ratio="15">{{user.email}}</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected" ng-click="checkedValue(user)"> </td>
          <!--<td st-ratio="20" class="text-right">
            <button type="button" ng-click="editUser($index, user)" class="btn btn-primary">
              Approve
            </button>
          </td>-->
        </tr>
```

parent.controller.js

```
 $scope.newUserListModal = function () {
        $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                     templateUrl: 'app/access/accessModal/newUserModal.html',
                     controller: 'AccessModalCtrl',
                     size: 'lg'
               });
             $scope.modalInstance.rendered.then(function () {
                 $rootScope.$broadcast('show-user-list',$scope.userList);
               });
               /*$scope.modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedUsers) {
                 console.log(selectedUsers);
               });*/
    }
```

child.controller.js

```
angular.module('angularModelerApp')
  .controller('AccessModalCtrl', function ($scope,$uibModalInstance,toastr) {
  var selectedUsers = [];
  $scope.$on('show-user-list',function(e,data){
    $scope.userList = data;
  });

    $scope.checkedValue = function(user){
           $scope.selectedUsers = $scope.selectedUsers || [];
           if(user.selected){
               $scope.selectedUsers.push({ attuid: $scope.user.attuid,
                                           firstName: $scope.user.firstName,
                                           lastName: $scope.user.lastName,
                                           email:$scope.user.email
                });
                console.log($scope.selectedUsers);
           }
       };
});
```

Comment: Isn't `$scope.modalInstance` a child controller? So you can directly invoke its methods and access its fields.

Comment: is there way to do same in child controller ? Or i am not sure how to invoke method using `$scope.modalInstance` if i can get some hint

Comment: why are you passing user to the function checkedValue  if user is supposedly on the scope? If user isn't on the scope why not just use what was passed to checkedValue?

Comment: @arrowd No, not in the sense of an Angular controller. `$.modalInstance` gives you access to the content container (things like dismissing the modal can be done with it), but doesn't help much for scope/view access.

Comment: Because each user has different value once checkbox is checked i will pass specific user information to checkedValue function there are different approaches i can do that but  first issue is  how to invoke method `checkedValue` ?